# Store a user's "rating" in profile or constantly run SQL queries to get average from separate table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

To get a user's average rating, should I run a SQL query each time that calculates the average from a different table, or store the current average in the user's profile for ease?

**To be more specific...**

I'm developing a user feedback/rating system. I have two tables, one called "users" and another for "comments." The comments table will encompass the comment, rating, and user ID. I'd like to get the average rating of a given user, which [obviously] is the sum of all ratings divided by the quantity of the ratings. I COULD run this query each time and collect all the rows, then do the math, OR...

To limited the quantity of queries to the database, just update the average in the "users" table. Each time a new comment/rating is added, the user's row will be updated as well.

Is this more advantageous? Will it improve page loads? Any advice is welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good way to think. The term is called "overhead". It's how much, in system resources, your application takes.

What I would do, if I were you, is this

1. Upon user login, calculate the average and store it inside your session
2. When a user submits a rating, recalculate at the time you save the new rating, and store the new value.
3. If you're just storing this average rating in general (like a user info page), I would calculate the average and store it in the user record and adhere to #2 on recalculations. A simple query still consumes less resources than an aggregate one.

Answer (score 0):

I would ignore how many queries the database has to handle until you actually have a performance bottleneck. Otherwise, you run a serious risk of optimizing prematurely (which, as we know, is the [root of all evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#Quotes)).

For now, just choose the simple option:

- the one you are most comfortable with (and therefore, will create the best solution for)
- the one that involves writing less code now (as a general rule the less code you write, the less bugs you can create)
- the one that you can finish sooner and move on to the next task (or go home early today)
- the one that will be clearer to other developers who have to maintain your code in the future

That sort of thing.